# Determining the validity of conclusions based on two assumptions (WFF'N PROOF )

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

The Logic Problem, taken from WFF’N PROOF, The
Game of Logic, has these two assumptions:

1. “Logic is difficult or not many students like logic.”
2. “If mathematics is easy, then logic is not difficult.”

By translating these assumptions into statements involving
propositional variables and logical connectives, determine
whether each of the following are valid conclusions
of these assumptions:

- a) That mathematics is not easy, if many students like logic.
- b) That not many students like logic, if mathematics is not easy.
- c) That mathematics is not easy or logic is difficult.
- d) That logic is not difficult or mathematics is not easy.
- e) That if not many students like logic, then either mathematics is
  not easy or logic is not difficult.

---

Here's my solution (in detail). I'm not sure if I did all this correctly. I just want to make sure if I made any mistake!

$D(x):$ "$x$ is difficult"
$S(x):$ "Many students like $x$"

$l$ and $m$ to represent logic and mathematics.

Assumptions:

1. $D(l) \lor \lnot S(l)$
2. $\lnot D(m) \to \lnot D(l)$

Conclusions:

- a) $\; S(l) \to D(m) $
- b) $\; D(m) \to \lnot S(l) $
- c) $\; D(l) \lor D(m) $
- d) $\; \lnot D(l) \lor D(m) $
- e) $\; \lnot S(l) \to (D(m) \lor \lnot D(l)) $

I'm quite sure that the **first conclusion (a) is valid**.

$
1) D(l) \lor \lnot S(l)
$
: Assumption 1

$
2) S(l) \to D(l)
$
: Logical equivalence of (1)

$
3) \lnot D(m) \to \lnot D(l)
$
: Assumption 2

$
4) D(l) \to D(m)
$
: Contrapositive of (3)

$
5) S(l) \to D(m)
$
: Hypothetical syllogism on (2) and (4)

The **second conclusion (b) is invalid** because since the conclusion (a) is valid and this conclusion is
$
D(m) \to \lnot S(l) \equiv S(l) \to \lnot D(m) \not\equiv S(l) \to D(m)
$

The **third conclusion (c) is invalid** because the assumption (2) is not equivalent to this conclusion:
$
\lnot D(m) \to \lnot D(l) \equiv \lnot D(l) \lor D(m) \not\equiv D(l) \lor D(m)
$

The **fourth conclusion (d) is valid** because the assumption (2) is equivalent to this conclusion$
\lnot D(m) \to \lnot D(l) \equiv \lnot D(l) \lor D(m)
$

The **last conclusion (e) is invalid** followingly according to the rules of inference:

$
1) D(l) \lor \lnot S(l)
$ :Assumption 1

$
2) \lnot D(m) \to \lnot D(l) \equiv \lnot D(l) \lor D(m) \equiv \lnot D(l) \lor (\lnot D(l) \lor D(m))
$

$
3) \lnot S(l) \lor (\lnot D(l) \lor D(m))
$ : Resolution rule on (1) and (2)

$
4) S(l) \to (\lnot D(l) \lor D(m))
$ : Logical equivalence of (3)

$
5) S(l) \to (\lnot D(l) \lor D(m)) \not\equiv \lnot S(l) \to (\lnot D(l) \lor D(m))
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Saying that a conclusion in propositional logic is valid means that
   it is tautologically true, which is not what you really mean. If the
   premises are true *and* the [***argument***](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813) is valid, then you could
   simply call the conclusion “true” (instead of the stronger “valid”).
2. Your translations, and your proofs of (a) and (d), are all correct.
   For ease of reading though, I am
   resymbolising the three atomic propositions:  
   $P: \quad D(l)$
    $Q: \quad S(l)$
   $R: \quad D(m)$
    Assumptions:
      (1) $P \lor \lnot Q$
       (2)
   $\lnot R \to \lnot P$
    Conclusions:
       (a) $\;
   Q \to R $
       (b) $\; R \to \lnot Q $
      (c) $\; P \lor R $
       (d) $\;
   \lnot P \lor R $
       (e) $\; \lnot Q \to (R \lor
   \lnot P) $
3. Your disproof of (b) is invalid. Firstly, you've merely shown that
   the (derived) true statement (a) isn't logically equivalent to
   conclusion (b); this is a weaker assertion than that (a) doesn't
   entail (b). Besides, so what if (a) doesn't entail (b)? If, for
   example, premise (1) entails (b), then that's sufficient for
   conclusion (b) to be true, isnt it?

   To disprove conclusion (b), just cite the truth assignment
   $(P,Q,R)=(T,T,T),$ which immediately has the premises both true
   yet conclusion (b) false.
4. Your argument in (c) is fallacious for the same reason.

   Instead, the truth assignment $(P,Q,R)=(F,F,F)$ immediately
   disproves conclusion (c).
5. Your argument in (e) has 3 errors: firstly, as above, conclusion $Y$
   can be a consequence of premise $X$ without being logically
   equivalent to $X;$ so the non-equivalence in line 5 does not
   disprove conclusion (e).  Secondly, the equivalence in line 2 is
   false; but I think you meant implication instead, in which case it
   is true.  Thirdly, line 3 is not a valid inference step.

   In fact, conclusion (e) $$\lnot Q \to (R \lor \lnot P)$$ *is* true
   whenever the premises are true. Now, by the definition, the
   conditional $\to$ is true whenever its consequent (i.e., the part of
   the proposition after the arrow) is true, right? Well, according to
   part (d), whenever the premises are true, the consequent of the
   conditional statement (e) *is* true. Therefore, conclusion (e) is
   true.

---

**Addendum** (see comment below)

[image]

Comment: Why did we use the truth assignment (P, Q, R) = (T, T, T) to disprove (b), but (P, Q, R) = (F, F, F) to disprove (c)?

Comment: @SokhibjonZamonov Each of those two sets happens to be the only one that works for the respective conclusion. I just added the truth table for (c); try constructing a similar one for (b). ([This tool](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool) is handy. I've also added link in Point 1.)