# Q does not follow logically from P

Tags: logic

If $P \implies Q$ and $not P \implies Q$ then can we conclude that Q does not follow logically correct from P?

Someone on the MathStackExchange asked a question that 'why "Socrates is a martian and martians lives in pluto therefore 2+2=4" is logically incorrect?'

I wrote suppose the given statement is P => Q. now assume not P but since we can prove Q from the notions of basic algebra. so P=> Q and not P=> Q which means P has nothing to do in the truth value of Q... so
I said Q does not follow logically from P... is that correct?

Comment: You can't prove Q from P, or not P, in this case.

Comment: This question originates from a previous question [What is meant by "logically incorrect"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738640/89922).

Comment: If "logically correct" is taken in the same sense as in your previous question, then $Q$ might well logically follow from $P$ (and maybe also from $\lnot P$). This is the basis of a proof by "distinguishing cases". Say, take $P:=x\ge 0$ and $Q:=x^2\ge 0$. If $x\ge 0$ then $x^2\ge 0$. If, however, $x<0$ then $-x>0$ so $x^2=(-x)^2>0$. Ultimately, in both cases $x^2\ge 0$. Having said that, it may not "logically follow" from either. Say both $P\implies Q$ and $\lnot P\implies Q$ are true if $P:=$"Socrates is Martian" and $Q:=2+2=4$ but $Q$ doesn't "logically follow" from either $P$ or $\lnot P$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop So Socrates is Martian therefore 2+2=4 does not logically follows isn't it? I said that there in the question mentioned above but my response got removed there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am editing your Question within the quotation blocks below instead of directly above, in case I've misunderstood your query.

> If $P \implies Q$ and $\lnot P \implies Q$ then can we conclude that
> $Q$ does not follow logically from $P$?

**Whether** given `P⟹Q` **or** given `(P⟹Q) and (¬P⟹Q)`, it *is* accurate to assert (literally) that **Q follows from P**.

> Suppose that the given statement is $P \implies Q$. Now assume $\lnot P.$
>
> So, $P\implies Q$ and $\lnot P\implies Q.$

But `¬P⟹Q` is *not* a consequence of `(P⟹Q) and ¬P`.

> This means that $P$ has
> nothing to do in the truth value of $Q.$

`(P⟹Q) and (¬P⟹Q)` means precisely that Q is a logical validity; as such, Q's truth value is not generally dependent on P's truth value. Even so, P and Q need *not* have “nothing to do” with each other: they can even stand for the exact same sentence, say `1=1`.

> In this case, is this correct: $Q$ does not follow logically from $P? $

$Q$ not *logically* following from $P$ means precisely that `P⟹Q` is not a logical validity; if P and Q are *arbitrary* sentences, then Q does not in general logically follow from P. On the other hand, `P or Q` does logically follow from  `P and Q`.

Comment: ohh ohh I got that in many cases Q may follow logically even if $P \implies Q$ and $\neg  P \implies Q$,... as one gave in the example above $x>0 \implies x^2>0$... so we can't say Q may not follow logically from P... now my question is how can we abstractly say that in "Socrates is a martian and martians live in pluto therefore 2+2=4" 2+2=4 does not logically follow from "Socrates is a martian and martians live in pluto"

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP 1. `P⟹Q` *literally* means `Q follows from P`. $\quad$ 2. Say, you assign specific meanings to P and Q such that Q follows from P; I would still refrain from saying that that Q *logically* follows from P, because some readers understand "logically follow" to have a stronger meaning than "follow".

Comment: @PraveenKumaranP 3. `2+2=4` *indeed* does not logically follow from `Socrates is a martian and martians live in pluto`; as explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738668/21813), you can also just say that `Socrates is a Martian and Martians live on Pluto, therefore 2 + 2 = 4` is an invalid argument.